# why is Requiring mongoose from local file is not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

#### So I have the code

Directory/app/script.js:-

```
// MongoDb
// Connect to MongoDB through Mongoose
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27012/profiles')

// Requiring the Schemas
const SignIn = require('MongoDb/Models/profiles.js')

console.log(SignIn)
```

So what is wrong in the code. The console in the web says that require is not defined. Can you help me with how to go about it.

Comment: "The console in the web says that require is not defined" — Do you mean the web **browser**? You've tagged this question [tag:node.js]. Run the code designed for Node.js in Node.js, not a browser.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Run the code designed for Node.js in Node.js, not a browser.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons you might get this error. Since you said

> The console in the web says

I expect it is the first reason in  your code

## You are running the code in a web browser

Node.js is a stand-alone environment for running JavaScript. It is not a browser extension.

To run Node.js code, save it in a file with a `.js` file extension, then run it with:

```
node yourFile.js
```

If you want Node.js code and browser code to interact then the typical way is to write a server in Node.js that hosts a web service. Express.js is a popular way to do this. You can then use Ajax to make HTTP requests to that web service.

For bi-directional communication (as opposed to the request/response of Ajax) look at Socket.io.

## You are using ECMAScript modules

Node originally used CommonJS modules which use `module.exports` and `require`.

Recent versions also support ECMAScript modules which use `export` and `import`.

Either switch to using `import` instead of `require` or [change your configuration](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system) to use CommonJS modules.

Comment: Ok so it works all perfect in the terminal but do i have to send create a new request to the mongodb. I already have the model ready but do i have to send a request to the main file  to create the data in the database?? And in the terminal it says my mongodb connection dose not work.